# How to enable bcmath module in PHP 7.1

Tags: linux, centos, php, centos7

Am running a Centos7 server. This module `bcmath` wasn't installed,

I installed it `yum install php-bcmath`.

And it doesn't seem to work. It also doesn't appear in info.php page.

The php version I have is 7.1.12 something.

How do I enable it?

Comment: How did you install PHP 7?

Comment: Followed a guide on digitalocean. But can't seem to find any info how to enable the bcmath module.

Comment: Which guide? Put simply, it's likely that PHP 7 isn't being installed from a default repository so you need to know the name of the repository (probably `php71-`).

Comment: How can I find that out? When I run `yum install php-bcmath` it says it is installed.

Comment: If it's [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-centos-7) you will be using the IUS repo, so try `yum install php71-bcmath`.

Answer (score 2):

For reference purposes, on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, with PHP 7.0, we use:

```
apt-get install php-bcmath
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP will be using an additional repository, usually IUS or Remi, so it is likely that you need to install the `php71-bcmath` package.

Comment: Says `No package php71-bcmath available.`
`Error: Nothing to do`.

Comment: It says it uses this repository:  `remi-php71: remi.schlundtech.de`

Comment: Use `yum --enablerepo remi.sclundtech.de install php71-bcmath`

Comment: Now it says this: `Failed to set locale, defaulting to C`
`Loaded plugins: fastestmirror`
`Error getting repository data for remi.sclundtech.de, repository not found`

Comment: Try `yum --enablerepo remi-php71` php71-bcmath` but also refer to the document that you followed to find what repo was set up.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for bumping an old post.

The problem was the command `yum install php71-bcmath`  should be

`yum install php7.1-bcmath`

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is:

```
sudo yum install php71-php-bcmath
```

in case you want to use remi's package https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=php71-php-bcmath

also after installing it, you probably want to restart apache server if you are running one:

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using centos on linux, and need to 1st find what exact package applies; then the command you're looking for is: `yum search bcmath`. This should return you a list of bcmath library applicable.

In my case it was: `yum install ea-php72-php-bcmath.x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

For Centos 7 with php7.0

1. Install CentOS SCLo RH repository:
   `yum install centos-release-scl-rh`
2. Install rh-php71-php-bcmath rpm package:
   `yum install rh-php71-php-bcmath`
3. Restart Apache
   `systemctl restart httpd.service`

Answer (score 0):

correct command is
yum install php71w-bcmath